# CSS layout for box with two text labels?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have an unordered list of items, I want to display each item as a box with two lines of text inside, each line with different properties (font, size, text-align...). The markup I am using for each item looks like this:

```
<li id="1">
    <p class="first"><!-- First line of text --></p>
    <p class="last"><!-- Second line of text --></p>
</li>
```

Using CSS I want it to display sort of like this:
[image: Layout]

My questions are:

1. I know this can be achieved in various ways with CSS, but **what is the right way or best practice** to do it for best cross-browser support? can you point me to a CSS example for something similar? the first text label should be 2 px from the top border and the second one 2 px from the bottom.
2. Is this the **right markup** for the text labels? or should I be using other tags instead of `<p>`? maybe `<div>`?

I am using `display: block` for the `<li>` tags, with fixed `width` and `height`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What browsers do you care about? IE6 (please no)? IE7?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to support IE6 too

Comment: Fortunately my solution works in IE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should be good:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/KbhHS/)

Tested in IE7/IE8 and recent versions of: Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera.
I also tested in IE6, works there to.

I'm only doing all this testing because you specifically asked for the "best cross-browser support" :)

I might be tempted to change the `<p>` tags for `<span>` tags, because these don't really seem to be paragraphs of text.

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 200%;
    line-height: 0.8
}
li {
    display: block;
    width: 140px;
    height: 100px;

    background: #ccc;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    margin: 8px 0
}
li .last {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 2px
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li id="l1">
        <p class="first">Text 1</p>
        <p class="last">Text 2</p>
    </li>
    <li id="l2">
        <p class="first">Text 1</p>
        <p class="last">Text 2</p>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: This almost works, however I need the text content area to be exactly 2 px from the border, I think maybe this can be handled with line-height but I end up giving it arbitrary values until I get the 2 px of space, but I don't really understand it, I wish there could be a more straightforward way to achieve it.

Comment: Also because <span> is diplayed inline I thought <p> was better, but maybe I could just modify <span> to display as block, or just use <div>

Comment: Here's a version where I literally changed `p` to `span`. It works the same: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/KbhHS/22/ - about the `line-height` thing - I'm not sure how you could handle it more elegantly.

Comment: This solution could be problematic if the text is resized by the user.

Comment: @Bryan Downing: Most browser zooms are (or default to) zooming in everything, not just text. Also, I'm not sure what I can do about it with the OP limitation of a fixed width and height `<li>`. Any ideas? :D

Comment: @thirtydot haha, ideas? No I just like to criticize :P I tried messing with `line-height` a bit, but it doesn't seem like it would be very reliable. I know most browsers zoom, but some users (like me) prefer text resize over zoom. Many websites also include custom text-resizing functionality. If it were me, I'd change the requirements here to be less strict or come up with a different idea.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a selector like this:

```
#1 p + p { padding-right: ..px }
```

Which if I know anything at all about CSS should get the adjacent sibling of the p element in #1

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
li
{
  display: block;
  padding: 2px;
  height: xxpx; /* The height that you gave the li */
  width: xxpx; /* The width that you gave the li */
}

li p
{
  height: xxpx;
}

li p.first
{
  float: left;
}

li p.second
{ 
  float: right;
  /*
  To place the 2nd text at the bottom right corner you need to give it a 
  margin top
  The value of this margin should be the total height of the li tag minus the 
  height of text (p tag) and minus the total vertical padding that is 4px.
  */
  margin-top: xxpx;
}
```

I guess that will do it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Added a live demo as well, thanks again thirtydot. http://jsfiddle.net/tsega/q9SBZ/4/